# Validate uniqueness on combined fields in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, validation, sinatra, datamapper

I want to be able to put entries in my database where the manufacturer will be represented multiple times but not the same combination of manufacturer and model.
So "Sony(manufacturer), Tv(model)" is okay "Sony(manufacturer), OtherTv(model)" but the third entry "Sony(manufacturer), Tv(model)" is not okay since the combination of manufacturer and model is not unique. I tried with the `:key => true` validation but it doesn't seem to work. And I cannot do something like `validates_uniqueness_of :manufacturer AND :model` I guess. So how do you do it?

```
class Tvs
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :manufacturer, String, :key => true
  property :model,        String, :key => true

  validates_uniqueness_of :
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually go with:

```
class Tvs
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :manufacturer, String, :unique_index => :manufacturer_model
  property :model,        String, :unique_index => :manufacturer_model

  validates_uniqueness_of :model, :scope => :manufacturer
end
```

This will also give you a unique index in the database.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. So this will give me a new column in the database called manufacturer_model or what?

Comment: Not a column, but a unique_index.  Called `unique_tvs_manufacturer_model` or something like that and over the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.
It seems this did the job:

```
class Tvs
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :manufacturer, String, :unique_index => true
  property :model,        String, :unique_index => true

  validates_uniqueness_of :model, :scope => :manufacturer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tvs
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :manufacturer, String, :unique_index => :manufacturer_model
  property :model,        String, :unique_index => :manufacturer_model

  validates_is_unique :model, :scope => :manufacturer
end
```

I needed to modify the example to use "validates_is_unique" to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `property :id Serial` line, you will end up with a composite key (Manufacturer, Model), that will not allow duplicate Models for a particular Manufacturer.